# Daisy chained modems on a range

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, daisychaining

I received a call today with a question that made me start rethinking things after we hung up. I can only provide the same information I was given so the details may not be enough to get an answer from you all, but I wanted to at least try to get some different input.

Situation-

A gun range is set up with 3 towers, each tower has a modem at the base. These modems feed to a series of daisy chained modems set in a box by each target. Each target has 2 modems in their respective box. One receives the incoming feed and the other pushes out to the next target.

The issue they are having is that when a single target is supposed to go down, it’s taking two other targets down at the same time.

Without being there and being able to network into anything it’s obviously hard to make a call. My general idea was possible was misconfigured modems/ IP conflicts more than wiring issues.

Thoughts?

Again this is all the info I have, and I’m only a year into the IT workforce so be easy. Lol

Comment: It sounds like people are shooting at these devices; is that the case, or are the devices merely relaying sensor data?  What does it mean to say that the "target" goes 'down' (is this a loss of connectivity, or specific sensor data that is interpreted as 'down', or?  Also, you use the term 'modem' a bunch.  Can you provide make/model of the device or a comparable device?  I'm having trouble figuring out if it is closer to a Hayes Accura 56k modem (for comms over POTS lines) or a cable-modem or something very different.

Comment: So, you're talking about control boxes for some kind of gun range target automation system, that's supposed to control when various targets pop up or "fall down" / "fold away"?

I doubt that system is really using modems of any sort. They're probably just a series of really simple relays or microcontrollers using very rudimentary signaling. MAYBE some kind of RS422 serial or something like that. It's probably not nearly as fancy as an Ethernet LAN with IP addresses.

This is probably a call for an industrial controls engineer (think of an HVAC wiring guy), not IT.

Comment: Assuming they are using the same kind of setup as other places around us. They should be using a RF-wireless modems, and yes they are shooting at pop-up style targets, that should go down as they are shot.

Comment: Can you link to a vendor of such a setup? There are lots of RF wireless modem technologies that are not Wi-Fi. If this is a Wi-Fi based system, it might be on-topic here. If it's not Wi-Fi based, it might be better for another Stack Exchange sister site, like maybe the electronics one.

Comment: Based off your comments, I checked back with the personnel who called. From off their description, I believe you are spot on. It seems like it is indeed a serial cable that is connecting them. I apologize for the confusion, and appreciate your time. I would’ve been spinning my wheels for hours trying to figure out how their “data cable” and “modems” were tied together. Lol

Comment: One target per tower, or how many? Please rephrase your question with what you have learned as well as the answer, by clicking [edit] here. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please click [edit].